# How to handle page breaks while extracting all product links for a particular Amazon seller

Tags: python, html, amazon-web-services, xpath

I am writing a Python program to extract the anchortags with hrefs matching a certain regex pattern from a seller page.

For example, my first seller URL starting with alphabet 'A' is as below:

[/s/ref=sr_in_A_p_6_1?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A2335752011%2Cp_6%3AA15LBIZFCJ59AM](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_in_A_p_6_1?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A2335752011%2Cp_6%3AA15LBIZFCJ59AM&bbn=2335752011&ie=UTF8&qid=1505299102&rnid=2491153011)

Now, what I want is to get all product links put out for selling by the above seller by scraping out anchortags with hrefs following below pattern

[/Apple-Factory-Unlocked-Internal-Smartphone/dp/B00NQGP42Y/ref=sr_1_1?m=A15LBIZFCJ59AM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00NQGP42Y)

But the list of products from the first URL is spread across multiple pages.

Given that I am using Python 2.7 with XPATH 1.0 string functions with regex, how can I handle page breaks?

Note: I am using Chrome Version 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Looks like you can just add `&page=3` to the end of your first URL, and iterate through the pages until you get to a page which has no product links (indicates you have gone past the last page) - is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Ken Syme: yes I can add but how will I know how many pages to add? the way you mentioned, I will have to keep on incrementing the pages but to what limit? or, shall I increment until some sort of PageNotFound Error raised by requests?

Comment: The simplest is to keep going until you get a page with an element with the `noResultsTitle` id. If you try it with the your link above, increment to page 7 and check `$("#noResultsTitle")`. You should see it appear on page 7 but not before.

Comment: Or you could look for the `pagnNextLink` id on the first page - if it exists it should contain the url for the next page. Can then loop over the next pages until there are no more.

Comment: You probably should read the part where it says [*"This license does not include any resale or commercial use of any Amazon Service, or its contents; any collection and use of any product listings, descriptions, or prices; any derivative use of any Amazon Service or its contents; any downloading, copying, or other use of account information for the benefit of any third party; or any use of data mining, robots, or similar data gathering and extraction tools."*](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/?nodeId=508088)

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options for doing this:

**Option 1**

Add `&page=3` to the end of your first URL, and iterate through the pages until you get to a page which has no product links / an empty message. You can check for the empty message by seeing if an element with the id `noResultsTitle` exists.

**Option 2**

Look on the page for the element a tag with an id of `pagnNextLink` - the href attribute of this is the next page. Load that and keep doing this until there is no next page link/no a tag with that id.